# How to install collada?

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I have found a model airplane that can be downloaded as a collada file, but I am still a newbie on Ubuntu and I need to know how do you install [Collada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COLLADA) on Ubuntu 12.04 Precise.

Comment: Welcome to AU, Do you really want to install Collada or just have the abilty to read the collada file you found.  The answer will be different based on your response as there are 3d model viewers out there that can read Collada files and some will even convert them to something more mainstream.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to view a *.dae* file you can use *meshlab*, which can be installed by

```
sudo apt-get install meshlab
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the official tutorial on How to Install Collada at [Collada.org](http://collada.org/mediawiki/index.php/DOM_guide:_Setting_up) .

Of course pointing you to an external tutorial is not a 100% answer,but the tutorial is way to big for me to post.